# Dynamic creation of ng-model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have property fields that contains string array:

in controller I have:

```
$scope.data = {};

$scope.fields = [
    "new0.name",
    "new0.type",
    "new0.address",
    "new0.city",
    "new0.postalCode"
];
```

in view I have:

```
  <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="f in fields">
    <label class="control-label">Some field name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="{{f}}" ng-model="data.f" class="input-xlarge">
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the **ng-repeat**, how can I concatenate value of **f**  to the `ng-model` to get, for example ng-model="data.new0.name"?

Comment: Ignore my answer below, have you tried `data[f]`

Comment: @tymeJV data[f] is solution. Thanks!

Comment: Posted a quick answer, was making it way too complicated at first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference a property of an object with a variable, use bracket notation

```
data[f]
```